# How to copy from other branch codes to my branch?

Tags: git

```
   A---B---C---D (master)
  / \     / \
 /    E---F  **J**  (my branch)
 \
  E----(**J**)     (my associate)
```

So the scenario is like this. Me and my associate pulled a copy from master and we began our work. But turns out I completed a task much faster than him and began to work on second task. So the situation is how is gonna get a copy of my work from (**J**)?

Comment: does `J` branch has only your commits?

Comment: You can [cherry pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) the commits which are necessary for you.

Comment: Your associate can pull master and rebase onto it, to get C (and D), but your associate cannot have J until you finish and merge it.

Comment: You have two different commits in your diagram that are marked `E`. Is the lowermost `E` supposed to be `I`? But then you also have two different commits marked `J`, which is not possible either. I can't quite make heads or tails of the drawing.

Answer (score 0):

If you have write access, you can push your branch `J` to remote, and your associate can then fetch and pull it to his own branch. Assuming your remote name is `origin`, you can do:

```
$ git push origin J
```

It would be better if he rebased the most recent `master` commits first before working with `J` branch, so your associate can do:

```
$ git checkout <associate's branch name> 
$ git rebase master   # Or at least commit C of master 
$ git fetch origin J
$ git merge <associate's branch name> origin/J
```

This will pull your remote branch `J` and merge it with your associate's current branch. If he would prefer to just pull branch `J` into a new local branch (not merged with his current branch), your associate can simply:

```
$ git switch J
```

This will create a new local branch `J`, then track and pull the remote branch `origin/J`